# Linux filesystem only readable, not writable via SMB

Tags: linux, samba, macos, file-sharing

I can typically access, open, and edit all the files inside my Linux machine that is connected via ethernet to my router simply by typing in `ssh user@192.168.0.10` into my macOS terminal. However, instead of purely interfacing through the terminal, I wanted to mount the entire filesystem of my Linux machine so that I could edit and freely transfer files to and from my Mac to the Linux machine.

macOS supports file sharing via SMB, so I decided to install Samba on my remote machine:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Then, I added the user `user` and a password to access the file share:

```
smbpasswd -a user
```

After this, I edited my Samba config file to contain the following:

```
[Volumes]
   path = /volumes
   writable = yes
   write list = user
   force create mode = 0777
   force directory mode = 0777
   public=yes
```

Finally, I restarted the Samba service:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

I was able to mount `Volumes` in the Finder using the username `user` and the password that I had set earlier. I am also able to read everything inside `/volumes`. However, I completely unable to modify any files or transfer anything into any folder in `/volumes`.

How do I actually make the folder writeable, instead of just readable? I added on lines such as `writable = yes`, `write list = user`, and `force directory mode = 0777` to my Samba configuration as shown above, but it didn't seem to have helped at all.

The output of `ls -l` on `/volumes` gives me the following:

```
ls -l /volumes
```

```
total 248
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 131072 Jul  3 01:06 bridge1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 102400 Jun 13 20:30 bridge2
```

Comment: Is `/volumes` writable on the system? Add the output of `ls -l` /volumes` to your question.

Comment: I edited it into the question, but it really happens with any file/directory in the whole filesystem, even files that I am freely able to edit when I ssh in as `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the files or directories inside of `/volumes` because only `root` has modify access to them. Based on what's happening, the same is also true for the `volumes` directory itself.

You either need to, as `root`, `chown -R user /volumes` to make `user` the owner so that it has modify access or else create a group, add `user` to it with `usermod -aG group user`, and then `chmod -R g+w /volumes` to give the group containing `user` modify access to the directory and its contents.

`force directory mode` only applies to directories that are created via `samba`. They don't have any effect on anything that already exists. In any event, you don't want to have `0777` as the mode because it allows anyone who has access to the system to write to the directory which isn't good for security.

Comment: I noticed that you're probably right; although I SSH in as `user`, when I type `who` although I see `user`, but if I type in `whoami` I see `root`. So perhaps my SSH commands are being carried out as `root` which made me think that `user` had modification access to this directory. However, when trying your `chown` command, even using `sudo`, I get the following error: `chown: changing ownership of '/volumes/bridge1': Operation not permitted` for every directory and file inside `/volumes`

Comment: @SkeletonBow You need to either be `root` or or have `user` be able to run with `sudoer` rights when changing ownership and permissions.

Comment: But am I not root? Because when I type in `whoami` it outputs `root`

Comment: Apparently not. If you ssh in as `user`, then you aren't in a root shell. You need to open one and then run the command(s).

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I thought there was a way to become root but I tried `su` and it didn't work either